# PHP debug recursion

Tags: php

I have a problem when I want to add debugging for recursion to send me the backtrace to show in which file an error occured (I'm not able to debug because the code is on another server).

I tried with:

```
register_shutdown_function(function(){
  // here i expect this function to be called and get the trace, but not
  die('error');
});
```

The docs say that the error will be called but it's not.

Sample code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

register_shutdown_function(function(){
    die('er');
});


function f()
{
    return f();
}

f();
```

Is there any other way to debug fatal errors and show backtrace for them?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. You're saying this shutdown handler isn't firing? You're saying you can't get a backtrace?

Comment: I cannot get the backtrace cause handler ins't firing. I've added sample code.

Comment: Still unclear to me. Did you try [error_reporting()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to debug?

Comment: I want to catch in which file the the recursion is called too many times. In the example it's visible but if you have 1000 classes and methods I cannot see clearly. Yes i've set error_reporting(E_ALL);